# Casting warning

Tags: plugins, spigot

```
private void loadGlobalChest() {
        ConfigurationSection inventorySection = items.getConfigurationSection("inventory");
        if (inventorySection != null) {
            globalChestInventory.setContents(((List<ItemStack>) inventorySection.getList("items")).toArray(ItemStack[]::new));
        }
    }
```

Can anyone tell me why when I try to cast List it gives me a warning? (which is Type safety: Unchecked cast from List<capture#1-of ?> to List)

It throws an error in the console, telling me that could not pass the InventoryOpenEvent because the return value of ConfigurationSection.getList(String) is null.

I think that probably the error is in the file where I store the items of the chest, because when there are no items, all the lines are null.

EDIT: https://pastebin.com/TxhY91HU

Comment: Your question is about the warning, or about the getList null ? Also, can you show the full error that said "could not pass InventoryOpenEvent" ?

Comment: @Elikill58 it is about the warning but I think I've found out a fix to that. Anyway the console does give me a could not pass InventoryOpenEvent error and I think is because in the yml file I use to store items, when there's no items the lines are null, I'll edit and post the full error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: This post should answer to your problem x) It's a common issue, the NullPointerException

Comment: It should, let me read it and see what I can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning is there because you are trying to cast a `List<ItemStack>` to a `List<Object>`. This is not a safe way to do it because the `List<Object>` could be any `Object` and you can't just cast a random object to an `ItemStack`. To make sure the objects you are getting from the config file are ItemStacks you need to check that each object in the `List<Object>` returned from `inventorySection.getList("items")` is an instance of `ItemStack`.

```
private void loadGlobalChest() {
        ConfigurationSection inventorySection = items.getConfigurationSection("inventory");
        if (inventorySection != null) {
            // Create a list of items
            List<ItemStack> itemList = new ArrayList<ItemStack>();
            //Loop though the list of objects in the config
            for (Object obj : inventorySection.getList("items")) {
                if (obj instanceof ItemStack) {
                    // If the object is an ItemStack, add it to the list of items
                    itemList.add((ItemStack)obj);
                }
            }
            globalChestInventory.setContents(itemList.toArray(ItemStack[]::new));
        }
    }
```

As for the null error, it is self-explanatory, It tells you the return value of `ConfigurationSection.getList(String)` is null. In the [spigot config](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/configuration/ConfigurationSection.html#getString(java.lang.String)) `ConfigurationSection.getList(String)` returns null "If the String does not exist and no default value was specified". The config section you are trying to get doesn't exist. You need to add a null check for the config section before using it and you need to make sure the list is saved in the config.